# Using raster iterator, failed raster to point conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, raster-to-point

I am trying to resample a gdb of rasters, extract them to my study area extent, and convert them to points.  The purpose of this is to have two raster data sets represented as points so I can export their tables and line the data up side by side for analysis. I am new to using the iterator in ModelBuilder.
Here is the model I am using,
[image]
However, I am getting the following error message:

> Possible empty feature class.
>
> Failed to execute (Raster to Point).

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to use %Name% in the outputs from all the tools (resample, extract by mask, and raster to point). I just tried this model with two rasters, and it worked well.
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the results

[image]

You have the option of putting the outputs from all the tools in the same geodatabase, or create a geodatabase for the outputs of each tool. 
Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Nice to hear that @Katherine Miller , please mark the answer as accepted so the question shows it is answered. Tnx

Comment: I need to export all of these point attribute tables to excel files.  Do you know a way I can do that with an iterator as well?  Or maybe I should write a script to try to do this by looping through a raster list?

Comment: I would try the table to excel conversion tool using a iterator. Let me know if it worked for you.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000

Comment: Here is another link http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012471

Comment: Should I use a feature classes or dataset iterator?  Also I am unable to connect the iterator to the table to excel conversion tool.

Comment: I tried running it in Python shell and I was able to create a list of the datasets but couldn't process the table to excel